# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно грамотно писать?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте!
подскажите как правильно: 
Согласно графикА или согласно графикУ и почему
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/418347) от [@Ruslan Kutliakhmetov](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177492) не совсем правильный. В современном русском языке предлог *согласно* требует дательный падеж, это литературная норма. Вот и всё, в принципе.

Comment: Лучше обозначать ответ ссылкой на ответившего вместо слов "выше" или "ниже", потому что они имеют тенденцию перемещаться, если их рейтинг меняется.

Comment: А вы на время посмотрите. Так сразу понятно становится.

Comment: Не хочу я на время смотреть. Заботьтесь сами о правильном оформлении своего ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно графику (согласно кому/чему). Слово "график" в дательном падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно запомнить **правило**: Производные предлоги БЛАГОДАРЯ, СОГЛАСНО, ВОПРЕКИ управляют **дательным падежом** существительных.

Почему? Основным значением Д. п. является **направленность в соответствии с предметом**: иду по дороге, подошел к дому, рад встрече.

Что касается производных предлогов БЛАГОДАРЯ, СОГЛАСНО, ВОПРЕКИ, то здесь по ошибке часто используется **Р.п.**, по аналогии со сходными сочетаниями или значениями, например:

благодарить (кого?)  тебя - благодаря (кому?) тебе,

исходя (из чего?) из графика - согласно (чему?) графику.